# Set maximum fan speed

Tags: hardware, firmware

Is it possible to set the maximum computer fan speed on the latest Macs, ideally with Terminal? I understand this is a terrible idea as it will likely lead to hardware overheating and failing, but I'm curious if that level of control is still available. From what I can tell, popular options like smcFanControl only set the minimum temperature.

Answer (score -1):

Just found one software option - https://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control - this can set a constant fan speed. I tested and was able to set a fan speed below the auto level. Still would be nice to find a Terminal command.